# Is it possible to specify multiple connection points in RMQ .NET?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

As the title states I would like to provided multiple URI's for the RMQ .NET `ConnectionFactory` in the hope that it will fail over automatically to the first available one, rather than being limited to a single URI.

**Setup**

Using the *Docker Quickstart Terminal* (part of *Docker Toolbox*) I have created *four containers*, each with it's on RMQ instance running on it.
I have clustered the RMQ nodes as follows:

- Downstream (node1 and node2)
- Upstream (node3 and node4)

The *Downstream* nodes share a [Federated Queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-queues.html) with the *Upstream* nodes to increase the throughput.

**Use**

I have written a simple console application in C# that will generate and publish messages to node4 (the primary upstream RMQ instance).

I would like to test the redundancy/automatic failover of my RMQ configuration as I have set the flags for `AutomaticRecoveryEnabled`([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#topology-recovery)) and `TopologyRecoveryEnabled`([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#topology-recovery)) and have the *Federated Queue* setup.

However, the `ConnectionFactory` provided by the RMQ .NET library doesn't appear to support specifying multiple URI's ([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#connecting)). So I have had to manually code in the handling of switching between the nodes when they go down - I do this by catching the exception thrown when a node is no longer accessible then pinging all nodes to see which is active.

**Is there a way to give ConnectionFactory multiple Rabbit endpoints so that it can failover automatically?**

Comment: Using the C# client provided by pivotal, no. You will have to do exactly what you are doing Im afraid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @chris.ellis. If you want to add this as an answer per se I'm happy to mark it as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the C# client provided by pivotal, no. You will have to do exactly what you are doing Im afraid.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [ConnectionFactory](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/e8f0a3aca3ab16ca3f2537dbc78543c91ff58f92/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs) it can create a connection with a [list of hosts](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/e8f0a3aca3ab16ca3f2537dbc78543c91ff58f92/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs#L384)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a connection using a list of hostnames. The first reachable
    /// hostname will be used initially. Subsequent hostname picks are determined
    /// by the <see cref="IHostnameSelector" /> configured.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hostnames">
    /// List of hostnames to use for the initial
    /// connection and recovery.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>Open connection</returns>
    /// <exception cref="BrokerUnreachableException">
    /// When no hostname was reachable.
    /// </exception>
    public IConnection CreateConnection(IList<string> hostnames)
    {
        return CreateConnection(hostnames, null);
    }
```

And by the way the below code:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.Uri = "amqp://user:pass@hostName:port/vhost";
IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Will call `CreateConnection({UriHostname})` with a list of single element

If you need a connections list between different cluster (different vhost, username, password...), so the answer is no, you cannot do that with the pivotal client. If only the hostname change, I may works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example @Nicolas, unfortunately I need this to occur between clusters.